# My /dev/sda4 disk space is full. I have allocated 70GB, I don't think it is full. I tried to fix the problem but don't know how to resolve this

Tags: disk, disk-usage, disk-management

[Here I attached screenshot error that you can look into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhRWK.jpg)

Comment: Yep. It's full. Regardless of how you *feel* about the state of the storage, numbers seldom lie. How much space is in your `/var/log` directory? That's generally the first place to look to free up space. `sudo apt clean` is also an option, as that will remove cached `.deb` files where possible. Otherwise, you will need to use `du` to determine which directories are consuming the most space, and make decisions appropriately 

Comment: Please edit the question: have the title briefly reflect the content of the question, then elaborate on the problem in the body of the question.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @matigo I inspected log files and removed journal directory of logs. When I run du -h command to see the disk usage I got the same result.

Comment: @heynnema, I can't open the gparted as disk is full.

Comment: @Suresh  Use the `Disk Usage Analyzer` to determine what's taking up the space, then you might be able to fix it.

Comment: Ubuntu(20.04)  currently running on /dev/sda4/. Can anyone tell me how could I see /dev/sda4 files and their sizes respectively in descending sorted order?

Comment: @heynnema, Is it possible to use Disk Usage Analyser on tty3 mode?

Comment: No, DUA is a GUI app. You'll have to use ls, df, and du. Look in /var/log first. You could also boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and then use DUA.

Comment: @heynnema, the problem got solved. It was due to the swapfile which was around 38GiB which I deleted

Comment: @Suresh Good find, but you'll need to create a new, smaller /swapfile for the computer to operate properly. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and I'll put together a quick answer for you on how to do that.

Comment: heynnmema, here is my swap configuration and other command details that you requested:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_5-JzCK_3LCrcqKiKvYrXWC6P7q3Q5Ru-ZZ-gVW8Bf4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You do not think it is full. However, it *is* full as indicated by the output of `df`.

A root space that is full is problematic and can cause your system increasingly malfunction. Move as quickly as possible some user data to another drive to create space again. Make sure your root partition never is filled more than 80%.